# CA credential installation on android below 4.0 version doesn't work

Tags: android, https

Below code successfully install CA on 4.0 and onward but its doens't work on below than 4.0.Does any body have any idea what i'm doing wrong.

```
private void showCAInstallationDialog() {
    try {
        InputStream caInputStream = getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.ca);
        if (caInputStream != null) {

            byte[] result;

            result = IOUtils.toByteArray(caInputStream);

            // The next line actually installs the certificate
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.credentials.INSTALL");
            intent.putExtra("name", getString(R.string.app_name) + " CA ");
            intent.putExtra("CERT", result);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CA_CERTIFICATE_ADDED);

        } else {
            Utility.logError(getSimpleName(),
                    "Error occurred while reading CA");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code - (if you still need the answer)

```
java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert;
byte [] certArray = //conver this "cer" to PEM using PEMWriter (use bouncy Castle library "bcprov-jdk15-140.jar")

Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent("android.credentials.SYSTEM_INSTALL");
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.CredentialInstaller");
intent.putExtra("CACERT_" + "nameOfCert" + "CA", certArray);
mContext.startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Thanks.